# Maven: The Definitive Guide - POM for 'asm:asm-commons:pom:3.2:runtime' is invalid

Tags: maven-2

I'm trying to go through the examples in Maven: The Definitive Guide. In chapter '4.3. Creating the Simple Weather Project' it has me run the following command.

```
mvn archetype:create -DgroupId=org.sonatype.mavenbook.ch04 -DartifactId=simple-weather -DpackageName=org.sonatype.mavenbook -Dversion=1.0
```

I think these errors are a problem.

```
[WARNING] POM for 'asm:asm-commons:pom:3.2:runtime' is invalid. It will be ignored for artifact resolution. Reason: Failed to validate POM for project asm:asm-commons at Artifact [asm:asm-commons:pom:3.2:runtime]
[WARNING] POM for 'asm:asm-util:pom:3.2:runtime' is invalid. It will be ignored for artifact resolution. Reason: Failed to validate POM for project asm:asm-util at Artifact [asm:asm-util:pom:3.2:runtime]
[WARNING] POM for 'asm:asm-analysis:pom:3.2:runtime' is invalid. It will be ignored for artifact resolution. Reason: Failed to validate POM for project asm:asm-analysis at Artifact [asm:asm-analysis:pom:3.2:runtime]
[WARNING] POM for 'asm:asm-tree:pom:3.2:runtime' is invalid. It will be ignored for artifact resolution. Reason: Failed to validate POM for project asm:asm-tree at Artifact [asm:asm-tree:pom:3.2:runtime]
```

because later I on get the message this

```
[INFO] Failed to resolve artifact.

Missing
--------
org.apache.maven.archetype:archetype-catalog:jar:1.0
org.apache.maven.archetype:archetype-common:jar:1.0
org.apache.maven.archetype:archetype-registry:jar:1.0
org.apache.maven.archetype:archetype-descriptor:jar:1.0
```

I ran the command again with debug on and I've included the output in a pastebin link

```
mvn archetype:create -DgroupId=org.sonatype.mavenbook.ch04 -DartifactId=simple-weather -DpackageName=org.sonatype.mavenbook -Dversion=1.0 --debug > mvnoutput.txt
```

http://pastebin.me/e50a3e5fa84cd8e8ff9336b3c3062d7f

I really have no idea why this is failing. I tried to navigate to the POMs manually using the

http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=asm/asm-commons/3.2/asm-commons-3.2.pom along with the other POMs and they look fine to me (but I'm trying to learn Maven.)

Here is my mvn effective settings. I left out the schema stuff at the very beginning. I am behind a proxy, but everything else seems to download fine. Any help would be much appreciated. I'll answer questions or post more information if you leave them as comments.

```
<localRepository>C:\Documents and Settings\~removed~\.m2\repository</localRepository>
<proxies>
<proxy>
  <active>true</active>
  <username>~removed~</username>
  <password>~removed~</password>
  <host>~removed~</host>
  <nonProxyHosts>~removed~</nonProxyHosts>
  <id>optional</id>
</proxy>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most important thing is to start with Maven 3.0.4 instead of Maven 2.0.8. Furthermore you need to use:

```
mvn archetype:generate
```

instead of

```
mvn archetype:create
```

Take a look into the docs of the [archetype plugin.](http://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/usage.html)

And one thing i recognized is that you are using an old book: Take a look into ["Maven by Example" book](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule-sect-simple-weather.html) and ["Maven: The Complete Reference"](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/public-book.html).

Comment: I know that create is deprecated from the mvn help goal. I'm trying to learn Maven 2 because it's what our company uses. I didn't realize I had an old version of the book, I'll check out the new copy. Thanks for the links!